# Get address of expression that would return a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Today I saw a piece of code in the firmware of an embedded device where they reference an expression that would result in a pointer. Something along the lines of:

```
struct test {
    int x[3];
};

int main() {
    struct test t;
    t.x[0] = 1;
    t.x[1] = 2;
    t.x[2] = 3;
    
    struct test *p_t;
    p_t = &t;

    printf("p_t->x: %p\n", p_t->x);
    printf("&(p_t->x[0]): %p\n", &(p_t->x[0]));
    printf("&(p_t->x): %p\n", &(p_t->x));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p_t->x: 0x7ffe49dd2abc
&(p_t->x[0]): 0x7ffe49dd2abc
&(p_t->x): 0x7ffe49dd2abc
```

The question is, is the third expression legal? I assume this is undefined behavior, but seems to (accidentally) work? Or am I missing something here?

From context in the code I can deduct that the goal is to get the pointer to the array inside the struct. I would have written it like the first expression, but the code contains a mix of the second and third expression. The second expression does seem valid, but the third one seems like they forgot the '[0]' at the end.

Tried the examples in some piece of C code described above.

Comment: The address of an array, and of the first element of said array, is the same value. Does not seem unusual to me.

Comment: This is legal, it isn't UB. It's a bit confusing, but basically with static arrays in C, the address of the array is itself. `p_t->x` is a pointer to the array, and `&p_t->x` is the address of the array: they're the same thing.

Comment: The name of an array (or better said, the address of an array) would mean ```&array[0]```

Comment: Strictly all 3 `printf` have undefined behavior because `%p` expects a void pointer but the passed pointer is another type. That said, it's completely legal to take the address of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions are *legal* but they should be cast as `(void *)` when passed to `printf` for the `%p` format.

`p_t->x` is an array, which decays as a pointer to its first element when passed to a function (or used in an expression, except as the argument of `sizeof` and `alignof`).  In the context, it is exactly equivalent to `&(p_t->x[0])` or, without the redundant parentheses, `&p_t->x[0]`.

`&(p_t->x)` (same as `&p_t->x`) is a different thing: it is the address of the array `x` of 3 `int`, not the address of its first element.  Both addresses refer to the same memory location, so `%p` will print the same thing, but with a different type: `int (*)[3]` instead of `int *`, so `&p_t->x + 1` and `p_t->x + 1` would output a different address.

Here is a modified version with 8 expressions printing the same address:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int x[3];
};

int main(void) {
    struct test t = {{ 1, 2, 3 }};
    struct test *p_t = &t;

    printf("       p_t: %p\n", (void *)p_t);
    printf("    p_t->x: %p\n", (void *)p_t->x);
    printf("&p_t->x[0]: %p\n", (void *)&p_t->x[0]);
    printf("   &p_t->x: %p\n", (void *)&p_t->x);

    printf("        &t: %p\n", (void *)&t);
    printf("       t.x: %p\n", (void *)t.x);
    printf("   &t.x[0]: %p\n", (void *)&t.x[0]);
    printf("      &t.x: %p\n", (void *)&t.x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are weird™.

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize an array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The *expression* `p_t->x` has type "3-element array of `int`" (`int [3]`); since it isn't the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, that expression "decays" to type "pointer to `int`" (`int *`) and is equivalent to `&p_t->x[0]`, yielding the address of the first element.

The expression `&p_t->x` has type "pointer to 3-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[3]`) and yields the address of the entire array.

Since the address of the array is the same as the address of its first element, all of `p_t->x`, `&p_t->x[0]`, and `&p_t->x` yield the same address value, but the types of the expressions are different:

```
Expression        Type        "Decays" to
----------        ----        -----------
    p_t->x        int [3]     int *
&p_t->x[0]        int *       n/a
   &p_t->x        int (*)[3]  n/a
```

This matters when doing pointer arithmetic. Both `p_t->x + 1` and `&p_t->x[0] + 1` yield a pointer to next `int` object in memory (equivalent to `&p_t->x[1]`).  However, `&p_t->x + 1` yields a pointer to the next *3-element array* of `int` following `x`:

```
                +---+
0x80001000:  x: |   | x[0]   <--- &p_t->x[0], p_t->x, &p_t->x
                + - +
0x80001004:     |   | x[1]   <--- &p_t->x[0] + 1, p_t->x + 1, &p_t->x[1]
                + - +
0x80001008:     |   | x[2]
                +---+
0x8000100c:     |   |        <--- &p_t->x + 1
                + - +
                 ...
```

This behavior is unique to arrays; struct and union expressions don't decay to pointers the way arrays do.

There *is* a reason for this behavior; it allowed Ritchie to retain B's array subscripting behavior (`a[i] == *(a + i)`) without having to reserve storage for the explicit pointer that behavior required. But it means array expressions lose their "array-ness" in most contexts.